# Specific usage of Android ListView

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I'm filling a custom ListView (by custom I mean with a specific layout) with a json request, an i'd like to implement an OnItemClickListener. So i did that :

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MessageList);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {


        }
    });
```

My problem is that I want to exploit the selected item of the ListView, but I can only know which item has been selected (the first one, second one, etc), i'd like to associate my Database's ID (the primary key i got with json deserialize) with the ListView ID, or something like that.

Is there any way to do this ?

Best regards.

Comment: ListViews can take any kind of object. Encapsulate everything you need  (including ids, etc.) in a Class that you've created and play with those objects in your listview.

Comment: Hi. Already using a class for this ListView, you want me to add an int id; (with getters and setters) in it ?

Comment: Yep - listviews should be *just* for display and interaction, so you should pass `List`s with everything you need to them. I don't know what you are modelling but it seems like you need some kind of id field in there. I can elaborate in an answer if you prefer.

Comment: I'm modelling messages, for being short, with author, message, date and unique ID. I'm using an ArrayList<MyClassWithGettersSetters> and an instance of that MyClassWithGettersSetters class. Between each message, i do ArrayList.add(Instance); and in the end listView.setAdapter with a custom adapter. I can link you the code, if it may help...

Comment: I've posted an answer - let me know if it doesn't make sense... obviously I'm guessing but basically you can get the item you want in the onclick...so as long as that item contains the id you need (setup earlier when you created your list/items)...you should be golden!

Comment: Sadly, the item do not contain the ID, juste the strings :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `MyClassWithGettersSetters` contains the database id that you need.

Then you can access items like so:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MessageList);
lv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        MyClassWithGettersSetters objectClicked = (MyClassWithGettersSetters) myAdapter.getItem(arg2);
        Log.d(TAG, "Clicked on object: " + objectClicked);
        objectClicked.getDBID(); // you now have access to the specific object and id
        // do whatever you need to do
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, two little issues with this ... First, the "  lv.setAdapter(myAdapter.class)," throws an error : "The method setAdapter(ListAdapter) in the type ListView is not applicable for the arguments (Class<myAdapter>)". Also, the get method of myAdapter doesn't exist in my code, what it this one ? Thanks.

Comment: I meant getItem (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem(int)) - I assume you are extending BaseAdapter to make a custom adapter. Anyway, good luck! Consider encapsulating everything you need in this class, I don't know why the id's aren't in there, I would put them there.

Answer (score 2):

In your Adapter, override `getItemId()` to return the Id you are using:
(in this example, your adapter works on JSONObjects, and your id is the long referred by the key "id" in your json object)

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return getItem(position).optLong("id");
}
```

This way, in your `onItemClickListener`, the `arg3` actually is the id of the clicked item.

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution and "Cannot invoke optLong(String) on the primitive type int", it seems optLong needs a string...

Comment: apparently your items are int, but i cannot say much more without seeing your actual adapter... (obviously, blind code requires some adaptation...)

Answer (score 0):

When you create your view, set the database id as the tag on the view. in your onclick, you can call arg1.getTag() and get that value back.

Comment: Hi, In the creation of the ListView, witch object am i supposed to apply setTag on ?

Comment: the view you are returning. your convertview.

Comment: Ok, so witch method can give me the current view ? I think i can win with this solution.

Comment: onclick will rpovide you with the view you clicked on.